# Unlike to NSPopupButton, NSArrayController's selectedObjects is linked to NSTableView selection

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, interface-builder

When i create NSArrayController that is binding to NSTableView fields, NSArrayController selectedObject property is "linked" to NSTableView selection automatically.

The same operation with NSPopUpButton has no effect on selectedObject.

Why ?

Comment: Your information is too poor. Tell, how you did what and what is the result, difference from the expected result.

Comment: What's the end goal here, do you want to know how to bind to a pop up button?

Answer (score 1):

You may get what you want if you use popup.selectedItem.representedObject